# missing formal parameter in constructor

Tags: javascript

unexpected token: identifier

i've changed the name of the constructor but nothing happens

```
// this is my javascript code 
var budgetController = (function() {

    var Expense = function(id, description, value) {               //Constructor for the EXPENSE which starts from Capital letter
      this.id = id;
      this.description = description;
      this.value = value;
    };
```

unexpected token: identifier

Comment: No idea what you're trying here, but you need to close your delimiters before anything will work.

Comment: you didn't close the `IIFE`.

Answer (score -1):

You're not closing it ()

```
 var budgetController = (function() {

        var Expense = function(id, description, value) {               //Constructor for the EXPENSE which starts from Capital letter
          this.id = id;
          this.description = description;
          this.value = value;
        })(); //Here's the problem
```

Comment: it's a typo, I don't think it should be answered as a comment would suffice.

Comment: By closing that bracket its saying that is "un-expected token"